# Last used column / find row with max no of columns in excel

Tags: java, python, excel

how do we find the last used column in excel using Java or Python ?

For example:

```
    F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  F6  F7  F8
 R1 x   x   x   x               
 R2 x   x   x   x       x   x   
 R3 x   x   x   x   x           X
 R4                     X   X
```

I would like to find the last used column / cell in the excel file. In this case Column F8 on Row 3 or Find Row3 because it has more no of columns, then check the last column in the row.

I was thinking of using POI(XSSFRow) to iterate through each row to find the max column but is there an alternative to find the last used cell without iterating each row, something similar to **CTRL+END** on a workheet ?

Comment: What is the file type? Can we use CSV? What would you want returned if R5 also had a value in F8? It sounds like you want a return of (row, column) tuple, not the value itself (x)?

Comment: File type is xls. Ideally I like to find which row has the most columns..... i.e. return max no of columns in a row ...So I would expect 8 as a result but I am ok if I even identify the row that has more columns, I can use that row to count the no of columns. If more than one row has same no of columns, return any row no because I am only trying to count max no columns. I prefer this in Java than Python unless it is not doable in Java which I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import petl

table = petl.fromxlsx('samplefile.xlsx') #File path, in this case right next to my script
largest_column = 0
for row in petl.data(table):
    for counter, value in enumerate(row):
        if value is not None and counter > largest_column:
            largest_column = counter
print "The largest Column found with data was {0}".format(largest_column + 1)
```

Don't forget to pip install

```
pip install petl==1.0.11
pip install openpyxl==2.3.5
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Y8DKzNb.png]

Comment: thanks, works as intended(tested locally). trying to figure out if same can be done in Java too as I may not be able to install pip in my environment due to restriction.